# Proof of circle's formula in complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, circles

I am asking about the proof of the complex form of circle's equation.
The formula is: $z=a+re^{i\theta}$, where $0<\theta < 2\pi$. I just know that $re^{i\theta}$ is the same as $r(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))$ using Euler's identity, but I don't know how to relate this to the formula above. Also, I don't know where $a$ comes from.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Complex_numbers) should help you rewrite it as $|z-a|=|r|$ (presumably $r>0$): $a$ is the centre, $|r|$ ($r$ on the aforementioned assumption) is the radius.

Comment: Geometrically, you translate the circle of radius $r$ with center at the origin by any complex number $a$.

Answer (score 0):

A circle centered at $a$ and of radius $r$ can be written a $|z-a|=r$.

This is equivalent to $z=a+re^{i\theta}\,,0\leq \theta<2\pi$.

To verify replace $z$ and $a$ by the cartesian coordinates and show that they satisfy $(x-a_{1})^{2}+(y-a_{2})^{2}=r^{2}$ where $a=a_{1}+ia_{2}$

Answer (score 0):

For the following it would be more helpful to think of the vector notation of complex numbers .
$re^{i\theta}$ represents a vector of magnitude r that makes an angle of $\theta$ with the positive x axis . This can be observed from this formula
$$r(\cos(θ)+i\sin(θ))$$
The complex number **a** represents the location of the center of the circle on the argand plane.
Now you can imagine a vector with its tail at point a that has a constant magnitude that rotates around point **a**  to form a circle.

**Mathematically**

$$a = c+di$$
$$z = c+di+r\cos(\theta) + ri\sin(\theta)$$

$Re(z) = c + r\cos(\theta)$ = x - coordinate

$Im(z) = d + r\sin(\theta)$ = y - coordinate

$$(x-c)^2 + (y-d)^2 = r^2$$

This is equation of circle